# add new column to datatable which contains total of other column with specific conditions

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, lambda, datatable

I have a datatable with few values as given below.

```
dtLabel     | size    | QTY
----------------------------
2015/11     | 204      | 272    
2015/12     | 204      | 235    
2015/11     | 204      | 254    
2016/01     | 204      | 259
```

I am looking for a way to add new column to datatable which contains total 
for QTY  for a given dtLabel
So new datatable should look like this

```
dtLabel     | size    | QTY   | TotalQTY
--------------------------------------
2015/11     | 204      | 272  |  272+254
2015/12     | 204      | 235  |  235
2015/11     | 204      | 254  |  272+254
2016/01     | 204      | 259  |  259
```

Linq or lambda would be helpful
Thanks

Comment: You need a column with an expression, take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/447249/Calculated-Columns-in-NET-DataTables-Csharp

Comment: I was thinking about using expression but cannot figure out what will be the xpression to calculate the totals

Comment: But where do you obtain the "total" value from? I overlooked the question and thinked it was just a column*column expression...

Comment: total is calculate form QTY Column for example each row with dtLabel 2015/11 contains TotalQTY as sum of all the values of QTY column with dtLabel 2015/11

Comment: how? qty * size? qty * number of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a datatable like this:

```vb
Dim dataTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
dataTable.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
dataTable.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
dataTable.Columns.Add("Size", GetType(Integer))
dataTable.Columns.Add("Qty", GetType(Integer))
dataTable.Columns.Add("TotalQty", GetType(Integer))
dataTable.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dataTable.Columns(0)}
```

And your datatable data is this:

```vb
dataTable.Rows.Add(New Object() {1, New DateTime(2015, 11, 1), 204, 272})
dataTable.Rows.Add(New Object() {2, New DateTime(2015, 12, 1), 204, 235})
dataTable.Rows.Add(New Object() {3, New DateTime(2015, 11, 1), 204, 254})
dataTable.Rows.Add(New Object() {4, New DateTime(2016, 1, 1), 204, 259})
```

So we can use a combination with GroupBy,SelectMany and Sum to calculate the **TotalQty** field

```vb
Dim results = dataTable.Rows _
                .Cast(Of DataRow) _
                .GroupBy(Function(s As DataRow) s.Item("Date")) _
                .SelectMany(Function(rows) rows.Select(Function(row) Tuple.Create(row.Item("Id"), rows.Sum(Function(dataRow) dataRow.Item("Qty")))))

For Each result As Tuple(Of Object, Integer) In results
    dataTable.Rows.Find(result.Item1).Item("TotalQty") = result.Item2
Next
```

Then we can show the datatable data with the TotalQty calculated

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
    Console.WriteLine("> Date: {0}, Size: {1}, Qty: {2}, TotalQty: {3}", row.Item(1), row.Item(2), row.Item(3), row.Item(4))
Next
```

The output is:

> Date: 01/11/2015 00:00:00, Size: 204, Qty: 272, TotalQty: 526
>
> Date: 01/12/2015 00:00:00, Size: 204, Qty: 235, TotalQty: 235
>
> Date: 01/11/2015 00:00:00, Size: 204, Qty: 254, TotalQty: 526
>
> Date: 01/01/2016 00:00:00, Size: 204, Qty: 259, TotalQty: 259

Comment: if the point is to show this in a gridview, you can save the trouble of using a `DataTable` as in WPF any Enumerable type can be auto-bind with the gridview. But it is the matter of taste.

Comment: @Baninder Yes, I will

Comment: @Baninder why the c# tag if that code is a mystery to you?

Comment: @Albero sorry for that ,its hard to find good answers for vb.net :)